# Division of complex numbers when to use what sign

Tags: complex-numbers, divisibility

I have two examples of dividing complex numbers, but both do the sign differently.

The first is:

$$\frac{a+bi}{c-di} \cdot \frac{c+di}{c-di}$$

the other is:

$$\frac{2-3i}{5+2i}\cdot\frac{5-2i}{5-2i}$$

In the first the signs match the signs next to them, then in the second they are both $-$. How do I know what signs to use for this?

Comment: If intended as a way to divide $a+bi$ by $c-di$, the first is simply wrong.

Comment: Guess it's just a typo then, cause that's what's on the paper we were given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply by the conjugate of the denominator.

$$
\frac{2-3i}{5+2i}\cdot\frac{5-2i}{5-2i}=\frac{10-19i-6}{25+4}=\frac{4-19i}{29}
$$

Comment: Ok, so from what I've read about conjugates, what about the first example I have where it's the same sign, not negated, in the top half of the right side?

Comment: The first seems incorrect since you're not multiplying by 1.